# Написать переход между двумя ViewController-ами

Tags: xcode, swift, mobile-development

Здравствуйте!
Возникла необходимость написать "руками" переход (по клику кнопки) между несколькими ViewController-ами( переход должен осуществляться при выполнении некоторого условия).

Comment: и в чем проблема состоит?

Comment: Код нужен) Я могу прокинуть через storyboard, но это будет не правильно.

Comment: что пробовали, что не получилось?

Comment: Просто нужно, что бы переход осуществлял при выполнении некоторого условия. А точнее после появления всплывающего окна, информирующего пользователя вызываемого кнопкой. Таким образом саму кнопку отключать нельзя, и переход не должен осуществляться при не выполнении условия. То есть самое простое, написать "переход" руками в нужной части кода. Думаю там 1-2 строки кода. Не более.

Comment: Вы бы хоть приложили что есть на данный момент. Какое хотите точно условие, как организовали в интерфейс билдере и т.п.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3**
в сториборде во втором контроллере куда вы хотите перейти укажите в `identity` -  `YourVC`, где `Main` это название сториборда.

в зависимости от условия меня класс и соответственно меняй `identity`

```
let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let initialVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourVC")
self.present(initialVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Работает!!!!!!!